# SQL analytical function: rank() over partition by not working property

Tags: oracle11g, partition-by, oracle-analytics

```
CREATE TABLE customers
( customer_id number(10) not null,
  customer_name varchar2(50) not null
);

INSERT INTO customers VALUES(22,'W');
INSERT INTO customers VALUES(22,'W');
INSERT INTO customers VALUES(20,'Q');
INSERT INTO customers VALUES(20,'Q');
COMMIT;
```

Now i am trying to get different rank corresponding to my partitions by customer name

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) , CUSTOMER_ID FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

**ouput:**

```
1   20
1   20
1   22
1   22
```

**expected output:**

```
1   20
1   20
2   22
2   22
```

Answer (score 1):

use below query

```
SELECT 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) , 
CUSTOMER_ID 
FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

remove **partition BY** by clause because if u use partition by clause it will divide the result based on name.